# Redirecting console output to file won't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, io-redirection

I'm trying to redirect the output of the following script to a file

```
REM go to the caffe root
cd ../../
set BIN=build/x64/Release
"%BIN%/caffe.exe" train --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt
```

I have tried :

```
REM go to the caffe root
cd ../../
set BIN=build/x64/Release
"%BIN%/caffe.exe" train --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt > caffe.log
```

and also

```
REM go to the caffe root
cd ../../
set BIN=build/x64/Release
"%BIN%/caffe.exe" train --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt 1> caffe.log 2>&1
```

But none of them works. It's weird though, if I use a simple Windows command like `dir` it works, but not the output of my application! What's wrong here?

Comment: What outputs to the console when there's no redirect applied? And bear in mind that you change directory as part of your batch script, so the output will be in the new directory. And change your forward slashes to backslashes :)

Comment: there is no file created at all, I'd checked that already several times. 
windows takes care of forward slashes as if they were slashes. the script works just fine, it executes well, but the output is not redirected. 
I actually have to use another batch file to get the out put for this batch file to redirect to a file!.

Comment: Windows command processor replaces `/` by ``\`` as it can be seen on running your batch file from within a command prompt window. But it is nevertheless better to use backslashes already in batch file and do not depend on auto-corrections of command processor. The questions here are: What is the current directory on starting batch file? What is the current directory after ``cd ..\..\``? Has the account used to run the batch file permissions to create and modify files in that directory? And is `caffe.exe` a console application at all?

Comment: @Mofi: Thanks, 
the user has administrative privileges ,
Caffe is a console application, 
and the current directory is :` T:\Caffe\Examples\Cifar10`
and two directory back is `T:\Caffe` as you can tell.

Comment: Well, in such cases I suggest using free [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor). Download and extract this tool, start it and define as filter __Path contains caffe__ then __Include__ and __Add__ this filter before pressing __OK__. The last 5 icons on toolbar determine what to show. Toggle off all except __Show File System Activity__. Then execute your batch file and look on *Process Monitor* log where you should see now what happened.

Comment: @Mofi: Thanks. I see how it goes

Comment: That's what I asked above. What is actually output to the console without the redirection? If it doesn't output anything, then nothing will be written to the file.